# Android - Run a block of code when volley response generated

Tags: android

In my android application, I use volley to get some information then dynamically create the layout. The problem is I want to add a button click listener to one of the views of the layout that created dynamically but I have to wait till the volley response. It's a button click listener so I can't put the OnClickListener in the response block, so here is the question: **How I can understand when the response is generated and put the OnClickListener in it?**

Comment: Um, why do you think you can't set the click listener in the response block?  There's no reason you can't.

Comment: Do you want to know when information is fetched?

Comment: @RohitSingh yes, exactly. and run a code like OnClickListener that need to be met after the java file loaded completely, so I can't use a boolean or something like that.

Comment: @NiethanX can you post the code

Comment: @GabeSechan are u sure? OnClickListener needs to be met even after the java file loaded completely so I can't put it in something like that

Comment: @NiethanX I have no idea what you're talking about.  setOnClickListener can be called at any time.

Comment: No it doesn't. The View can be accessible and a listener set before a layout is loaded... Add your code!

Comment: onSuccess call method which you want to perform on onClick

Answer (score 2):

try this when you get data from volley :

```
button.performClick();
 button.setPressed(true);
```

Comment: also do what you want at btn.setOnclicklistener

Answer (score 1):

**You can use BroadcastReceiver** to get notified when your data is fetched (or parsed).
You can do this way.
Write a Broadcast Message to tell that data is fetched.
You can do something like this in your **onResponse method of volley**

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {     

   try {
         // Parsing
         someMethod();   /// this is the method to notify idf data is fetched

       } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
       }

}
```

> someMethod()

```
public void someMethod(){
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction("Some key");
  sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

> Register Receiver in your Activity

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new YourReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("Some key");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

> Final step: Set your buttonListener inside onReceive() method of
>   Receiver

```
private class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

   private Context context;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Some key"))
        {

          //Set your button listener here  
        }
    } 
 }
```

**NOTE: Call you receiver after you register your receiver.(Avoid this common mistake).**
Here is the [starting point to learn Broadcast Receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html), if you are not aware of them.

`

Answer (score 0):

**Posting a method to post a Volley request. In the onResponse you may conduct your operation depending on your response like this:**

```
private void fetchData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(mURL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(expectedResponse){
                        Button mBtn=new Button(getApplicationContext());
                        mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Conduct your operation here
                        }
                        });
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(VolleyExampleActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

*Hope this helps.*

Answer (score 0):

On response block you can also write

```
Button dynamicButton = new Button(getActivity());
dynamicButton.setId(0X000000);
dynamicButton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener)getActivity());
```

On Click listener you can handle like this

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case 0X000000:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"To something",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I hope this help